# Magic Links specific for WordPress Answers

Tags: feature-request

In comments, I'm constantly using the [**Magic Links**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments): `[faq]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]` and `[about]`, this last one being quite nice given the [About Page 2.0](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/).

Would it be possible to have a couple of WordPress specific ones?

I'm looking at:

**`[debug]`**
http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

and
**`[troubleshoot]`**
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list

I understand that *troubleshoot* would have to be updated at every major WP release, so maybe it's not practical.

Comment: I did not even know this existed, I like `[debug]`.

Comment: @Wyck This is part of my [Markdown cheat sheet](http://labs.toscho.de/sidebar/markdown.html).

Comment: I had some free time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had some free time so I created a very simple chrome extension which work on the client side :)

First you add the "shortcodes" you want the the options panel

[image]

you get something that looks like this:
[image]

where you can add remove as many as you want.

then when you enter a comment you will see this new link
[image]

and When you click it you will get this:
[image]

It works both on meta and main site of WordPress answers, an di know there are many bugs but it gets the job done :)

sorce at : [**`https://github.com/bainternet/WPA-shortcodes`**](https://github.com/bainternet/WPA-shortcodes)

Comment: Can't believe it ¡?!¿ :::: **Are you for real?** :::: Aw̴͉̖̺̞ͥ̽ͧ̎ͩso̿̅̔̈me͇̫̤͉

Comment: <testing> Sorry, but you need to [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) this :P </testing>

Comment: You should release that on http://stackapps.com/

Comment: Maybe I'll make a more generic version for all SO network sites and then I'll release that to stackapps